# How to describe a rdfs:range with multiple values

Tags: rdf, rdfs

I have a class `stk:vzg`. Now i want to specify a property `stk:hasLa`, that has `stk:vzg` as the domain. I know i can do that as follows:

```
@prefix ...

stk:vzg rdf:type rdfs:Class .
stk:hasLa rdf:type rdf:Property ;
          rdfs:domain stk:vzg .
```

I also want to specify the `rdfs:range`, but that range consists of a blank node with multiple values. Something like this:

```
stk:hasLa rdf:type rdf:Property ;
          rdfs:domain stk:vzg ;
          rdfs:range [
                stk:begin xsd:string ;
                stk:end xsd:string ;
                stk:laElement stk:la
          ] .
```

Is this correct or how would I specify this correctly?

Tried the shown example but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: RDF Schema is not able to differentiate between URI nodes and blank nodes, all are resources. If your example is supposed to denote that the value of the property is a resource with particular other properties, that is also something RDF Schema cannot do, since it is never "restrictive", only used to imply information. Would OWL or SHACL be an option?

Comment: @IS4 OWL is also an option, thank you. Just wanted to know if it possible with rdfs.